# Wolfenstein (2009) level skip

Tags: pc, cheats, wolfenstein-2009

Anyone know how to skip levels in Wolfenstein? I lost my savegame and want to skip to the airship bit. I'm on a PC

Thanks!

edit: I found [this](http://m0001.gamecopyworld.com/games/pc_wolfenstein.shtml#Wolfenstein%20ALL%20LEVELS%20UNLOCKER%203), which basically looks like it adds savegames from all levels to your directory structure then alters wolf.cfg and config.spec. I'll give it a go and post back here if it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is for the original version of Wolfenstein only and can be enabled at any time during the game by holding 'Back' and pressing A, Y, A, Y. If entered correctly you will go right to the end level status screen.

Comment: "holding 'Back' and pressing A, Y, A, Y." makes me think that that's an Xbox code...

Comment: Yeah this was for PC but thanks anyway